# Why is checkbox not the same in IE7 and other browsers?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Why is the checkbox not the same in IE7 and other browsers?

For this code

```
<div style=" float: left; border: 1px solid;">
    <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 0px;">
</div>
```

Other browser (in this case Chrome) show like this.
http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/is/160306032913.jpg

And IE7 show like this (Looks like have `padding` or `margin`, I checked but not found).
http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/iv/160306032939.jpg

How can I change result in IE7 as same as other browsers using CSS?

Comment: This is the generic question about why different browsers have different default styling. You need to either overwrite them or use a "reset stylesheet" to nullify them. Then you should use an own stylesheet file (css file) where you place your styling rules instead of using those inline style properties ("style="..."). There are endless examples for that once you look for it.

Comment: To just find out what exactly is causing a certain gap or distance, use the browsers development consoles to examine the rendering. Take a look at the browser documentation about that or read a "getting started with web development" guide, those explain the basics.

Comment: Use a CSS reset stylesheet like Normalize https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Use a CSS hack to target only IE7, and set some negative margin.